# For which values of x does the sequence $a_n$ converge? (ratio test for $a_n=\frac{x^n}{n^3}$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence, ratio

I was wondering if anyone could offer any tips or hints as to how to tackle this question, I've tried looking around on here and in my notes but I can't seem to find anything.

> Consider the sequence
>
> **$$ {a_n=\frac{x^n}{n^3}}. $$**
>
> B1. Apply the ratio test to ﬁnd out for which values of $x$ the sequence $(a_n)$ converges.
>
> B2. For which value(s) of $x$ does the ratio test provide no information?
>
> B3. Does $(a_n)$ converge or diverge for these values? Justify your answers.
>
> B4. Give an example of a sequence that converges if $-1<x<1$ and diverges otherwise. Justify your answer.

Comment: In B$, you ask `[...] converges if $1<x<1$ [...]`. Do you mean $-1<x<1$?

Comment: Ah yes I do sorry

Answer (score 1):

By [ratio test](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-ratio-test-for-sequence-convergence) we obtain

$$\left|\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}\frac{n^3}{x^n}\right|=|x|\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^3 \to |x|$$

then for convergence we need $|x|<1$, then study separately the cases $|x|=1$.

Comment: Thank you for this, do you have any suggestions on tackling B4 or an example I could use?

Comment: @CAHL632 We have that $\frac{\left(\frac12\right)^n}{n^3}$ converges and $\frac{2^n}{n^3}$ diverges.

Comment: I think the question is looking for just one sequence which adheres to both rules instead of an example of each.